# No able to send array from front end (reactJs) to the backend (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

This is the code for on my front end
When the object `vendor` is sent to the backend, the array key, value pair `businessImages` is empty [I came to this conclusion when nothing got console logged when I tried logging `businessImages` in the backend]
When I console log the `vendor` object, from the front end, it clearly shows that `businessImages` is populated. I have no idea what's going on.

> Frontend code (reactjs)

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (businessImages.length > 15) {
      alert("You've selected too many images for your business");
      setBusinessImages([]);
    } else {
      const formDataBusinessImages = new FormData();
      const formDataProfilePicture = new FormData();
      vendor = {
        name: name.current.value,
        email: email.current.value,
        mobileNumber: mobileNumber.current.value,
        businessAddress: businessAddress.current.value,
        mainService: selectedService,
        subServive: selectedSubService,
        businessImages: [],
        aboutBusiness: aboutBusiness.current.value,
        minPrice: minPrice.current.value,
        maxPrice: maxPrice.current.value,
        featured: featured,
      };
      formDataProfilePicture.append("file", profilePicture);
      formDataProfilePicture.append(
        "upload_preset",
        process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_KEY
      );
      try {
        await axios
          .post(
            "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/devign/image/upload",
            formDataProfilePicture
          )
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("Profile pic uploaded");
            vendor.profilePicture = res.data.secure_url;
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      businessImages.map(async (image) => {
        formDataBusinessImages.append("file", image);
        formDataBusinessImages.append("upload_preset", process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_KEY);
        try {
          await axios
            .post(
              "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/devign/image/upload",
              formDataBusinessImages
            )
            .then((res) => {
              vendor.businessImages.push(res.data.secure_url);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });

      handleUpload(vendor);
    }
  };
  const handleUpload = async (uploadData) => {
    try {
      // console.log(businessImagesUrl);
      // console.log(uploadData);
      await axios.post("/auth/register", uploadData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

> Backend code (nodejs)

```
 router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newVendor = new Vendor({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    mobileNumber: req.body.mobileNumber,
    businessAddress: req.body.businessAddress,
    mainService: req.body.mainService,
    subService: req.body.subService,
    profilePicture: req.body.profilePicture,
    businessImages: [],
    minPrice: req.body.minPrice,
    maxPrice: req.body.maxPrice,
    featured: req.body.featured,
  });
  try {
    newVendor.businessImages.push(req.body.businessImages);
    console.log(req.body.businessImages, req.body.profilePicture);
    const vendor = await newVendor.save();
    res.status(200).json("Successfully registered");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: who said `FormData` is an array ?,  Its JS api for `multipart/form-data` . To upload files, your server should accept `multipart/formdata`  content-type instead of `applicaiton/json`. You can not read those directly, you need some sort of middleware that can parse `multipart/form-data` so use [`multer`](http://npmjs.com/package/multer) .